# Super Resolution using OpenCV4Android

Tags: android, opencv

Can anyone help me in implementing super resolution in opencv4android. I already have an android opencv project. I want to add super resolution to it.Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into this myself. My inputs are NV21 yuv420sp byte[] images. I haven't figured out yet how to use this input in the OpenCV super resolution method. It uses frameSource as input for the SR method and the constructor needs a video sequence as input apparently..

I asked how to do this on the OpenCV forum, and you will have to write in C++ and use JNI to include the super resolution part in your Android application:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/60085/super-resolution-on-android/

Some useful links:
Code examples:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/20318/super-resolution-cant-process-first-frame/

http://answers.opencv.org/question/26955/super-resolution-with-248-real-time-processing/

OpenCV sample of super resolution on their github:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/super_resolution.cpp

Hope this helps, and if someone managed to find some good tutorial for this, please let me know !

Comment: Did you make any progress on your project Pieter?

Comment: Unfortunately, no update from my side.